# Why I'm getting the PHP Fatal error in following scenario?

Tags: php, apache, fatal-error

I'm using LAMP on my local machine. I'm getting the following error in apache error log and a blank web page in browser when I hit the URL:`http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/admin/forgot_password.php`

Following is the error I got in apache error log:

```
[Tue Apr 15 17:10:18 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'includes/public-application-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/smart-rebate-web/web/admin/forgot_password.php on line 2, referer: http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/admin/login.php?lout=1
```

For your reference I'm attaching the image of my project structure titled '**smart-rebate-web**' in Netbeans editor.
[image]
and following is the sceenshot of abrwser after I hit the URL :

```
http://localhost/smart-rebate-web/web/admin/forgot_password.php
```

[image]

So can anyone please help me in resolving this issue please? Thanks in advance. If you want any further information or any code I can provide you the same. Following asre the permissons of these files if I print in terminal:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 eywa eywa 1646 Apr 14 13:05 application-header.php
-rw------- 1 eywa eywa 1006 Apr 10 18:06 public-application-header.php
```

Comment: Does the file that you are trying to include , have read permission?

Comment: @opensource-ios:I've updated my question as per your requirement. You can check the permissions at the bottom of a question. Now do you have any idea of resolving the issue?

Comment: Yes i have provided an answer you can try it and let me know if it works

Comment: @PHPLover you have permission issue. In your case, only file owner can read that php file. But, when you from browser, `www-data` user is used to read php files. To solve, see my answer for further detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have permission issue. According to your current file permission, only file owner can read and write that file, others cannot read. When you go on browser, default `www-data` user tries to read that file. And it is not permitted. Make your file `644` or change file owner to `www-data`. ``www-data` is the apache user used while you open php files from browser. And more flexible way, use following;

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/public-application-header.php");
```

Comment: I tried with your idea in a file forgot_passowrd .php it worked there. Did the same thing in case of change_password.php, but it's not working out there. Giving the same error. How to resolve this issue now?

Comment: Have you changed file permissions?

Comment: Change your root folder permission like `chown -R www-data:www-data path_to_web`

Comment: I've changed the permission and in terminal it looks like below:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eywa eywa 1646 Apr 14 13:05 application-header.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eywa eywa 1006 Apr 10 18:06 public-application-header.php

Comment: Change your root folder owner, that will resolve your issue. You need to use `chown -R www-data:www-data path_to_web`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
require_once('web/admin/includes/<filename>');
```

Comment: Also COuld you try giving your file 0755 as permission and then check